# Match HTML Comments With Grep and Regex

Tags: regex, grep

I have a series of files containing html comments (`<!-- some comment -->`) that I'm trying to match using `grep`

Comments span across only 1 line.

Here is my command

```
grep -rl '<!--.*?-->' ./
```

This doesn't match. However if I run grep with this regex:

```
grep -rl '<!--.*?' ./
```

It works.

The original regex works in javascript, but grep doesn't seem to like it for some reason unknown to me.

Thanks.

Comment: are comments spanning several lines? What do you mean with "fails"? It doesn't find all files with comments or it finds no match at all?

Comment: That code should work if you instead use `egrep`.

Comment: Yeah. I just tried egrep write before you wrote this and it worked.

Comment: out of curiosity, does it also work without the `-rl` options on a single file you know to have comments?

Comment: Yes, it works without options on a single file.

Comment: Hehehe, finally something to do with HTML that regex can be a good tool for (HTML comments are not nested so make a regular language)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default regex engine (POSIX basic) in grep does not support `?`.  This works, since `.` will also match the space:

```
grep -rl '<!--.*-->' ./
```

Comment: Grep will also not match across lines

Answer (score 0):

`Egrep` is another alternative.

```
egrep -r '<!--.*?-->' ./
```